# Permission issue with WordPress docker setup

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am trying to setup a WordPress project on my machine using Docker. This is my docker-compose.yml file code:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
    # Database
    db: 
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
            - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment: 
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
            MYSQL_USER: wordpress
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
        networks: 
            - wp
    # Web Server
    wordpress:
        ports: 
            - "4000:80" 
        depends_on:
            - db
        image: wordpress:latest
        restart: always
        volumes: 
            - "./html/:/var/www/html/"
        environment: 
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
            WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
        networks:
            - wp
networks: 
    wp:
volumes: 
    db_data:
```

This works fine but what it does is, that the files that are mounted inside ./html folder has user and group permission assigned as **www-data:www-data**. I am working on Ubuntu desktop OS. So every time I try to update any code inside ./html folder, I get **permission denied** message.

Is there any way I can fix this issue?

I have tried this command to add my user to www-data group but that didn't work aswell.

`sudo usermod -aG www-data aslam`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to match the user's id on the host machine to match that of www-data inside the container or vice-versa. May be read [this](https://faun.pub/set-current-host-user-for-docker-container-4e521cef9ffc) for more info and howto.

Comment: I tried that by adding user id inside docker-compose file like this

user: 0:0

As the user inside docker image has id 0.
I still get same problem.

Comment: oops, sorry it worked for me now. I had to delete the html folder and run docker-compose up again for this to work :)  thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To be clear for everyone else, adding `user: 0:0` to the docker-compose.yml file solved this issue for me too.

There isn't a problem with file permissions when you mount the files on windows... but I feel like mounting to Windows isn't a good idea because the response time to the application is very slow that way.

Here's the full docker-compose.yml

Running this in your WSL of choice will prevent the permissions issues.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  wptoolkit:

    # add user declaration to avoid windows permission issues when editing files and folders through your favorite editor
    user: 0:0

    # Ensure DB is up
    depends_on:
      - db
    # We'll use the most recent Wordpress install
    image: wordpress:latest
    # Map files from container back to linux at this directory location
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
    # We'll access our site on http://localhost:8999
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      # We'll provide some SQL credentials -- these match what's
      # in our db section
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress

  # This is our MySQL database server
  db:
    # We use a mariadb image which supports both amd64 & arm64 architecture
    image: mariadb:10.6.4-focal
    # If you really want to use MySQL, uncomment the following line
    #image: mysql:8.0.27
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=wordpress
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
      - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress
    expose:
      - 3306
      - 33060

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: pma
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:80
      
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Answer (score 0):

In case an error like that is shown by a plugin etc.: Ensure there are no other than permission based file system related issues (e.g. disk space limitations) by switching to the `www-data` user and reproducing the file operation manually, so the actual error message is revealed.